# Avoid user from deleting app data explicitly

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

- I am developing an app which requires data not to be cleared even if user explicitly tries to clear app data by going to settings or by uninstalling it. The data is of small size only.
- First I thought of using `SharedPrefrences` or `SQLlite` but data will be cleared when user will uninstall app.

So is there a way to do so. Do help me I am beginner developer.

Comment: You can save data to external storage.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that concept is contrary to the user's rights. They should be able to remove an App and everything associated with the App (assuming that they own the devices, a different matter if this was say a company providing the devices and the App).

However, if the data to be stored doesn't change then you could include it as an asset so whenever the app is installed the data can be copied from the package to the App's storage and therefore will effectively always be available and even provide updates to the data by making a new version of the App available.

If the data changes via the user, you could place the data into external storage (if the user permits for more recent devices), however the user still has the ability to delete that data.

A third option would be to store the data on a server/cloud. The issue would then be to distinguish users and to provide a suitable measure of privacy of that users data (basically the ability to logon securely).

Comment: What about internal storage? If I store data at Internal Storage it would be lost if user unistalls the data?And why you haven't recommended SQLlite or sharedpreferences?

Comment: @AndroidDev your question argues against internal storage, so was discounted by the question and therefore rules out shared preferences so SQLite is the only option according to the options provided in your question.